# Tuning Chip Antenna

Tags: pcb, antenna, bluetooth-low-energy

I am designing a BLE board with `nrf52832`. This is the first time I am designing a board having a `RF` part. After considering MIFA and Chip antenna, I have decided to use `Chip` antenna as I think it will be easy for me to incorporate in my design.

However, I read and do understand that `MIFA` antenna requires tuning by adjusting it's length as near-by material and/or pcb variation may change electrical length of antenna trace. And I think chip antenna should have provision to tuning but I am not aware of it. Do I need to tune a chip antenna? If yes, then how?

I am designing the board for [this](https://www.johansontechnology.com/datasheets/antennas/2450AT18B100.pdf) chip antenna.
The datasheet states the antenna has 50 ohm impedance. Can I skip matching network suggested in the datasheet if my antenna feed line (coplanar transmission line with ground plane in the bottom) is also of 50 ohm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cheap 2.4GHz Antenna Tuning](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/139374/cheap-2-4ghz-antenna-tuning)

Comment: @LiorBilia: If there is no difference between a PCB antenna and chip Antenna, then it is a duplicate question!

Comment: The process is the same, the tools are the same, for all purposes, it is the same.

Comment: @LiorBilia: Are you a RF engineer?

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate... it might be related, but not a duplicate